# A wide multi-page table to be made in a two-column elsarticle document

Tags: elsarticle, supertabular, sidewaystable

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,two column,number,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[htb]
\tablefirsthead{%
\textbf{Sl} & \textbf{Heading}&\textbf{City} &\textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading2}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Headinf3}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading4 (\%)}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading5 (\%)}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading6}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading7}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading8}}}& \textbf{Heading9} \\\hline\hline
}
\tablehead{%
\textbf{Sl} & \textbf{Heading}&\textbf{City} &\textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading2}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Headinf3}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading4 (\%)}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading5 (\%)}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading6}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading7}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading8}}}& \textbf{Heading9} \\\hline\hline
}
\tablelasttail {%
\hline\hline}  
\tablecaption{A multi-page table which should be in landscape mode on a two column elsarticle portrait document}
  \label{tab:Table6}
\begin{supertabular*}{\linewidth}{p{0.005\linewidth}p{0.15\linewidth}p{0.1\linewidth}p{0.005\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.28\linewidth}}\\

    1&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Adelaide, Australia&O&59.00&57.00&-29.00&28.99&9.65&0.25&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    2&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Austin, United States&O&1.00&1.00&-66.00&37.83&0.00&0.00&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    3&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Berkeley, United States&O&15.00&15.00&63.00&30.48&10.43&0.25&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    4&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Berlin, Germany&E&20.00&20.00&117.00&25.09&22.60&0.47&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
        5&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Christchurch, New Zealand&O&100.00&100.00&100.00&9.95&31.22&0.76&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    6&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Dunedin, New Zealand&O&39.00&31.00&54.00&29.25&9.65&0.25&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
7&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog &Graz, Australia&O&56.00&56.00&-60.00&32.16&8.06&0.20&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    8&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Gwalior, India&O&25.00&25.00&65.00&29.46&10.85&0.27&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    9&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Riga, Latvia&O&48.00&48.00&11.00&29.73&8.12&0.21&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\\
    10&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Stockholm, Sweden&O&90.00&90.00&134.00&4.85&34.74&0.88&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    11&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Sydney, Australia&O&46.00&46.00&89.00&23.72&16.28&0.41&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
\end{supertabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have tried almost everything I have seen in past questions but was unable to find a solution. I am new to LaTex so its possible that the mistake is simple.

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to complete, compilable small document.Note:  `sidewaystable` can be only one page big.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: @Bernard I need to make a wide, multi-page table in 'elsarticle' two-column document. The table is too wide to be accommodated in portrait mode. 'Longtable' isn't working because its a two-column document, 'sidewaystable' is not supporting page break, and 'supertabular' in landscape environment is getting converted to portrait text (I believe its because of the two-column style)

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for the info on sidewaystable. Didn't know that. Have edited the codes to show the complete document.

Comment: Maybe try the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use longtable and multiple pages here.  Not sure elsevier will accept it.

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,two column,number,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multicol}% ???

\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{afterpage}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcaptype}[1]{\def\@captype{#1}}
\newcommand{\AfterPage}[1]{\afterpage{\if@firstcolumn #1\else\afterpage{#1}\fi}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\AfterPage{\onecolumn\begin{landscape}
\setcaptype{table}
\tablefirsthead{%
\textbf{Sl} & \textbf{Heading}&\textbf{City} &\textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading2}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Headinf3}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading4 (\%)}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading5 (\%)}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading6}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading7}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading8}}}& \textbf{Heading9} \\\hline\hline
}
\tablehead{%
\textbf{Sl} & \textbf{Heading}&\textbf{City} &\textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading2}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Headinf3}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading4 (\%)}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading5 (\%)}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading6}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading7}}}& \textbf{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Heading8}}}& \textbf{Heading9} \\\hline\hline
}
\tablelasttail {%
\hline\hline}  
\tablecaption{A multi-page table which should be in landscape mode on a two column elsarticle portrait document}
  \label{tab:Table6}
\begin{supertabular*}{\linewidth}{p{0.005\linewidth}p{0.15\linewidth}p{0.1\linewidth}p{0.005\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.05\linewidth}p{0.28\linewidth}}\\

    1&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Adelaide, Australia&O&59.00&57.00&-29.00&28.99&9.65&0.25&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    2&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Austin, United States&O&1.00&1.00&-66.00&37.83&0.00&0.00&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    3&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Berkeley, United States&O&15.00&15.00&63.00&30.48&10.43&0.25&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    4&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Berlin, Germany&E&20.00&20.00&117.00&25.09&22.60&0.47&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
        5&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Christchurch, New Zealand&O&100.00&100.00&100.00&9.95&31.22&0.76&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    6&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Dunedin, New Zealand&O&39.00&31.00&54.00&29.25&9.65&0.25&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
7&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog &Graz, Australia&O&56.00&56.00&-60.00&32.16&8.06&0.20&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    8&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Gwalior, India&O&25.00&25.00&65.00&29.46&10.85&0.27&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    9&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Riga, Latvia&O&48.00&48.00&11.00&29.73&8.12&0.21&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\\
    10&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Stockholm, Sweden&O&90.00&90.00&134.00&4.85&34.74&0.88&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
    11&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog&Sydney, Australia&O&46.00&46.00&89.00&23.72&16.28&0.41&The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \\
\end{supertabular*}
\end{landscape}\twocolumn}

\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```